# Auth dialogue opens but closes immediately

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm planning to use the PHP-SDK to post user custom object actions. The PHP side of things work, but when trying to use the JavaScript SDK to auth the user prior to the post, I get a pop up load, but then shut down immediately. It's not being blocked as a pop - it loads but it is immediately shut down in a variety of browsers.

Note: I am mixing XFBML and HTML5 Like/Login below but it also happens when they use the same method. I am using custom namespaces to define the page in the OG, but I am not sure that matters.

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

...

<fb:like send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

...

<div class="fb-login-button" scope="publish_actions" data-show-faces="false" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1">Login with Facebook first to share your review.</div>
```

I have the app setup, enabled for Facebook login (although I am only using the login button to force permissions for posting this custom action).

Comment: are you logged into facebook when you test it?

Comment: @JohnB - Thanks - Initially I was, but I switched to the test user rather than the App owner account and it's happening the same.

Comment: Hmm, a good cache/cookie flush seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: It’s _supposed_ to happen if the user is already connected to your app and also has given the permissions you’re asking for already …

Answer (score 0):

Per comments above, this seems to be occurring because I was logged in as a user who already has the relevant permissions.